# Find common value within two array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Implement the find_common function. When passed two arrays of names, it will return an array containing the names that appear in either or both arrays. The returned array should have no duplicates.

```
<?php
class Names
{
 public static function find_common($array1, $array2)
 {
    $arr = array();
    foreach($array1 as $value1){
        if(in_array($value1,$array2)){
            array_push($arr,$value1);
        }
    }

    return $arr;
  }
}

$names = Names::find_common(['Ava', 'Emma', 'Olivia'], ['Olivia', 'Sophia', 'Emma']);
echo join(', ', $names); // should print Emma, Olivia, Ava, Sophia
```

OUTPUT SHOUD PRINT: Emma, Olivia, Ava, Sophia
What I am getting is only the Emma, Olivia :(

Comment: An actual question would be nice.

Comment: Just refer to the output. It should output : `Emma, Olivia, Ava, Sophia`

Comment: Can you add find_common as well ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
array_unique(array_merge(['Ava', 'Emma', 'Olivia'], ['Olivia', 'Sophia', 'Emma']));
```

`array_merge` will put all values in a single array then `array_unique` wil remove duplicates.

Comment: That's It!!!!! Thank you sir. Maybe you can help me more with my problem?

Comment: What problem do you still have ? Can't the answer be accepted ?

Comment: After 2 mins I can accept your answer! Can you pls give me your contact? I have many problems :(

Comment: Thanks but I won't have time to go through all your problems privately. But I'm not the only one who can help you here, don't hesitate to ask more questions !

Comment: One more problem. Pls give me your contact

Answer (score 1):

This is real easy. Use `array_intersect()`:

```
array_intersect(['Ava', 'Emma', 'Olivia'], ['Olivia', 'Sophia', 'Emma']);
```

Array will contain Emma & Olivia.

Check the docs! :-) http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

> UPDATE Your question doesn't reflect your desired output. Do you really mean to ask how to merge arrays without duplicates?

If that's the case, merge the array with

```
array_unique(array_merge(['Ava', 'Emma', 'Olivia'], ['Olivia', 'Sophia', 'Emma']));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: Your output is only `Emma and olivia`. Output should be `Emma, Olivia, Ava, Sophia`

Comment: He said the output should print Emma, Olivia, Ava, Sophia ;)

Comment: Yup so he needs a merge then. Updating

Answer (score 0):

```
$names = unique_names(['Ava', 'Emma', 'Olivia'], ['Olivia', 'Sophia', 'Emma']);
echo join(', ', $names); // should print Emma, Olivia, Ava, Sophia
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Try This works for me:

```
function unique_names(array $array1, array $array2) : array
    { 
     $array3= array_intersect($array1,$array2);
     return array_unique(array_merge($array3,$array1, $array2)); 
    }
```